# Impact of recoding variables on sampling weights

Tags: weights, survey-weights

I'm working on a dataset with longitudinal survey data that includes final post-stratification weights. I want to recode some of the demographic variables, such as race and income, to combine several smaller categories so as to have fewer categories to work with and larger cell sizes. However, it occurred to me that doing so might interfere with the validity of the sampling weights. Can anyone speak to this?